# getting all the keys for a map such as $_POST

Tags: php, dictionary

For example, say I post some data to a php file, but I don't know what the names of those values are.  Where I would normally perform `$_POST["username"]` or something similar. How would I go about getting a list of all the key/value pairs within `$_POST`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`array_keys($_POST)` will give you the array keys.

You can also do this to get values with key names:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
{
    //do stuff; 
}
```

However!!!  Why wouldn't you know what keys are in the post?  You don't want hackers putting random stuff into a post, sending it to you, and processing away.  There is nothing preventing them from putting in 1000s of entries.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, this isn't going to be a part of an actual system I'm building, it would just simplify some of the testing I'm doing while I get better acquainted with all the Ajax tricks jQuery can do.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to obtain all keys in `$_POST` super global array:

```
array_keys($_POST)
```

Simple example:

```
foreach (array_keys($_POST) as $key)
{
    print $_POST[$key];
}
```

Comment: That `foreach` is bad since it has to loop through all the elements twice instead of once.  First the system goes through the array constructing a new array for `array_keys()`, then it goes through it again in the `foreach()`.  That is an O(2n) operation rather than O(n) for just doing `foreach($array as $key => $value)` as I posted.